# What is wrong with my json marker?

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I'm trying to get my marker to show up. Clearly, I have to code
 for the marker.However, I have never tried to use an updating json object as my coordinates for my marker. I am using my knowledge to build this activity but all that shows up is the map. I have no errors whatsoever.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

// calling Retrievedata

```
new Retrievedata().execute();


}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady( GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    Marker marker;



    class Retrievedata extends AsyncTask<Void, Double, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {

                while (!isCancelled()) {

                    jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544");

                    Double lat = jobj.getDouble("latitude");
                    Double longit = jobj.getDouble("longitude");

                    // this will cause onProgressUpdate to be called with lat & long
                    publishProgress(lat, longit);

                    // it's okay to sleep within the background thread
                    Thread.sleep(1500);

                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.w("RetrieveData", "thread was interrupted", e);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("RetrieveData", "parse error", e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate(Double... values) {

            Marker marker;
            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(values[0], values[1]))
                    .title("ISS")
                    .snippet(""));
        }
    }


}
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();



}

protected void onDestroy(){

    super.onDestroy();



}
```

}

Comment: Seems You didn't create `Retrievedata` object (didn't start `AsyncTask`).

Comment: I tried adding this new Retrievedata().execute();

Comment: So please add full source.

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
new Retrievedata().execute()
}

Comment: Please add full source to question, not to comment (where You add `new Retrievedata().execute();`)?

Comment: you are creating a marker but never use it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to use a json object as my marker and i'm trying to update it and track it every few seconds.